# Разбить код результата

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Есть скрипт обработки ajax добавления комментариев на сайт.
Результат работы скрипта (data) берется для вставки в див comments

Как мне забирать из data определенную часть кода для вставки?

```
<script>

    var clickedButtonValue;

    $('button[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        clickedButtonValue = $(this).val();
    });

    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $("#commentadd").submit(function(event) {

        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault();

        /* get some values from elements on the page: */
        var $form = $(this),
                text = $form.find('textarea[id="userComment"]').val(),
                number = $form.find('input[id="num_clear"]').val(),
                url = $form.attr('action'),
                term = clickedButtonValue;

        /* Send the data using post */
        var posting = $.post(url, {
            like: term,
            text: text,
            num_clear: number
        });

        posting.done(function( data )
        {
            /* Put the results in a div */
            $("#comments").append($(data));

            $("#commentadd")[0].reset();
        });

    });



</script>
```

После нажатия получаем в data

> Good by: #27.0.0.# on 2016-02-09 07:13:47

Который вставляется в див comments.

Как разбирать этот data на части и вставлять например

В див comments:

> by: #27.0.0.# on 2016-02-09 07:13:47

В див comments2:

> Good

Comment: Средствами PHP или средствами JavaScript? В обоих есть функция `split` для строк.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
posting.done(function( data )
{
    /* Put the results in divs */
    var index = data.indexOf(" ");
    var data2 = data.substring(0, index);
    var data1 = data.substr(index + 1);
    $("#comments1").append(data1);
    $("#comments2").append(data2);
});
```